# Experiencing problems with KDE after an upgrade

Tags: kde, gentoo, kde4

After an upgrade of KDE I am experiencing problems. A lot of problems.

1. "Konsole" doesn't starts at all! (I have to switch to a console with ctrl+alt+Fx login with username, export DISPLAY=:0 and start "Konsole"). The worst is that the process start already "zombie" which is not very good!
2. It's not only konsole that I cannot launch. It is even dolphin and many more applications.
3. google-chrome starts but it takes eternity! Then when I try to download anything the download doesn't start! Internally google-chrome put the download on queue (it is not visible on "Downloads" page) but it never starts.
4. Application launcher menu takes ages to show up.

Anyone have any clue on these problems?
My distro is gentoo. If you need more details ask and I'll give.

EDIT: i forgot to say that if i launch application with root privileges, everything work fine.

Comment: This question belongs on http://askubuntu.com/, not here

Comment: funny but if you don't have experienced same symptoms simply don't answer

Comment: Oops, sorry, you're right, I saw the kde and thought kubuntu. Still, I am not sure this is the right forum for the question. Maybe try http://serverfault.com/, or try a gentoo forum.

Comment: I thought it was some sort of sarcasm =)  do you think i can post same problem even there to have more visibility or it would be considered some sort of spam? =)

Comment: Sorry, Gentoo is a "your installation is one of a kind, unique in all of the world" type of distribution. It is very unlikely somebody else messed up their system just like you did, so the probalility of getting any help is quite remote. Either redo the update, taking care to do it right, or get someboby knowledgeable in Gentoo looking over your machine.

Comment: i understand what's your point, but i think it doesn't concern at all with the kind of distro "i made". I already upgraded every single packet in the "right way" thinking that problems would be solved, but nothing..

Comment: I don't know what Benubird is on about, but if it's somehow unclear from the FAQ: asking about Gentoo problems is fine here. Same with Ubuntu problems for that matter, although if it requires a lot of Ubuntu-specific knowledge we generally move it to AU

Comment: I often have problems after a major upgrades of KDE. Unfortunately this usually means moving `~/.kde4` (or wherever gentoo is putting it these days to `~/.kde4.bak` and then logging back in. KDE basically sucks at migrating configs. You can then pick and choose a few configs to mv back such as ktorrent, konsole, konversation. (note: first login will take some time as it rewrites everything but things should be better on a 2nd login)

Answer (score 0):

As *xenoterracide* correctly suggested my KDE profile was messed up by a system upgrade. So simply do a backup of your KDE profile and restart KDE, then you can restore your configuration by hand.

Maybe it is obvious but for a complete answer i'll write operations I made.(I use a gentoo distro).

1. Go to a console `Ctrl+Alt+F2`
2. Login as user
3. stop KDE with `/etc/init.d/xdm stop`
4. do a backup of your KDE profile with `mv .kde4/ .kde4.bak`
5. restart KDE `/etc/init.d/xdm start`
6. pass to X with `Ctrl+Alt+F7`

Then you can restore configuration.